# Get time in milliseconds

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, milliseconds

I'm trying to get the time in milliseconds since a certain date. Here is my code:

```
startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
startDate = NSDate()

let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitNanosecond, fromDate: startDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)

println("\(dateComponents.seconds)")
```

(I did seconds to make it easier, but in the actual thing I will need milliseconds.) It gives me seconds, but after 59, it goes back to 0. (It's a timer. If you want I can show that code too, but I thought it wouldn't be necessary.)

How can I get it to show milliseconds and go all the way - I don't want it to start over?

**Update**

I tried the following:

```
let milliseconds : Double = [startDate .timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0
```

It then says to put a comma after `startDate`. After I do that, I get an error:

> Could not find member `'timeIntervalSinceNow'`

Comment: I tried the following: let milliseconds : Double = [startDate .timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0 It then says to put a comma after startDate. After I do that, I get an error: Could not find member 'timeIntervalSinceNow'

Comment: The above code is Objective-C, see in the answers of the duplicate question, I recently put an answer like the above but in Swift.

Comment: Thanks! I'll upvote your answer!